# React TypeScript - Passing type arguments to tagged template literals

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So I'm using React TypeScript for a project. I'm also using Styled Components for my styling - here's my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import MediaQuery from '../utils/MediaQuery'

interface ISectionHeading {
  headline: string
  subheadline: string
  body: string
}

export default function SectionHeading({
  headline,
  subheadline,
  body
}: ISectionHeading) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Heading headline={headline}>{headline}</Heading>
      <Subheadline>{subheadline}</Subheadline>
      <Body>{body}</Body>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.header`
  // Some styles...
`
const Heading = styled.h1<ISectionHeading>`
  // Some styles...

  @media ${MediaQuery.medium} {
    &:before {
      content: '${props => props.headline}';
      // Some styles...
    }
  }
`
const Subheadline = styled.h2`
  // Some styles...
`
const Body = styled.p`
  // Some styles...
`
```

I'm trying to pass my type arguments from the interface down to the styled component, as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props).

```
const Heading = styled.h1<ISectionHeading>
```

For some reason, I'm getting this error below. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
Failed to compile.

~/src/components/Heading.tsx
TypeScript error in ~/src/components/Heading.tsx(18,8):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ISectionHeading, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; headline: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ISectionHeading, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture">': subheadline, body
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"h1", any, ISectionHeading, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"h1", any, ISectionHeading, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; headline: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ISectionHeading, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "headline" | ... 256 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture">': subheadline, body  TS2769

    16 |   return (
    17 |     <Wrapper>
  > 18 |       <Heading headline={headline}>{headline}</Heading>
       |        ^
    19 |       <Subheadline>{subheadline}</Subheadline>
    20 |       <Body>{body}</Body>
    21 |     </Wrapper>
```

**Versions I'm using:**

```
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-dom": "^16.11.0",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
"styled-components": "^4.4.1",
"typescript": "3.7.2"
```

Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cloud-0ms6j).

Thanks for the help in advance!

---

> **Update:** So I just figured out if I made `subheadline` and `body`
>   optional types, it compiles successfully. I still don't understand why
>   I need to do this? It works fine on the sandbox without doing this.

```
interface ISectionHeading {
  headline: string
  subheadline?: string
  body?: string
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? There is no error on sandbox

Comment: That's strange, the only error I get on the sandbox is `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.` Why do I get the big error on VSCode?

Comment: Because of MediaQuery

Comment: I removed `MediaQuery` on my local version and I get the same error, like I said `MediaQuery` is just being replace with `min-width: 300px`.

Comment: I've also just noticed it's not actually working on the sandbox, if you hover over `headline` on line 30, it says it has the type `any`, so it's not even using the interface.